# Como crear n subprocesos que agregan m elementos a un List compartido entre todos los subprocesos?

Tags: java

Quiero escribir un método estático de `stressTest(int n, int m)`, que crea n subprocesos que agregan m elementos a un `MySafeList` compartido entre todos los subprocesos. El método debe devolver falso, si el número de elementos agregados es diferente del número esperado (n × m), o si se lanza una excepción durante la ejecución. Asegúrese de que su prueba falla con `MySafeList` no sincronizado.

Entonces intenté utilisar una lista static y crear una tabla de hilos.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MySafeList extends ArrayList<Double>{

    static ArrayList<Double> mySafeList;

    public boolean add(Double d){
        mySafeList.add(d);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int size(){
        return mySafeList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Double get(int i){
        return mySafeList.get(i);

    }

    static boolean stressTest(int n, int m){
        Thread threads[] = new Thread[n]; 
        try{
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                threads[i] = new Thread();
                threads[i].start();
                for(int j=0; j<m;j++){
                    Double d = new Double((double) j);
                    mySafeList.add(d);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySafeList safeList = new MySafeList();
        stressTest(2,4);    

    }

}
```

No sé si los n subprocesos han hecho todas las adiciones en la medida en que no he creado una ejecución.

Comment: el codigo posee errores de sintaxis (estas usando mal el for loop) te suguiero revisar tutoriales de como usar los loops y como declarar las variables. 
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp

Comment: Si vas a crear una clase con un método estático, he invocar ese método deberías invocarlo de forma estática. ¿Cual es el chiste de invocarlo de forma no estática?

Comment: @Silencio2, Si, tiene razon. Utilicé la respuesta de Alberto Lopez sin verificar.

Comment: @abrahamhs, En efecto. Me disculpe. Todavía soy un novato en java

Comment: el output que muestras se debe a que estas Irrespetando las firmas. 
por ejemplo add no es void. add returns boolean (ver https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html )
luego utilizas en un metodo estatico una variable que no es estatica eso genera el error MySafeList.java:30: error: non-static
return False; (false debe ser minuscula) 
todos estos errores son demaciado basicos y determinan un claro desconocimiento del lenguaje. sugiero que leas a profundida los tutoriales de Java officiales de oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html )

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thread threads[] = new Thread[n]; //El nombre de tu variable se llama "threads"
    try{
        for(int i=0; i==n; i++){
          //  Estas usando la variable t, y definiste la variable threads
          //  Thread t[i] = new Thread(new ThreadTest(1));
          // cámbialo a :
              threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadTest(1)));
            //  t[i].start();   // aquí estas usando la variable t[i], creo que
              threads[i].start();   // debería ser también threads[i]
            for(int j=0; j==m;j++){
                mySafeList.add(j);
            }
        }
```

Comment: esta respuesta esta mala. el For no compilara for(i=0; i=n; i++) (que es i ? ) int? float? double? i=n no es una comparación es una asignación. 
además de los errores de sintaxis. este código no está sincronizado, el usar threads para llenar un Array list es peligroso si no tiene una debida sincronización.

Comment: Hola @alberto. lamento el que tomes el comentario tan personal (y aparte de una respuesta de forma pasiva agresiva) cuando la intencion es mejorar la calidad de las respuestas. pero dejando eso de lado.  el segundo loop (for(j=0; j=m;j++)) aun esta incorrecto. aunado el problema de sincronización persiste, si bien se puede utilizar una synchronizedCollection, esta sugerencia no se realiza en la respuesta algo que para la practica y otros lectores es importante que se vea y se tome en consideracion.

Comment: @Silencio2 ya modifiqué ese loop que mencionas. Lo había copiado directo del ejemplo que puso y la pregunta era otra, pero tienes razón, no debería copiar algo incorrecto. Ya no voy a modificar la respuesta por que la pregunta original ya ha cambiado muchas veces, ya no sé que pregunta. Por otro lado te pido una disculpa por hablerte respondido agresivamente. Mi error.